# the 2.x version nacos useage in springcloud-alibaba：2022.0.0.0-RC1 ？

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, nacos

```bash
2024-01-11 15:36:46.868  INFO  [           main] (system) -- c.a.n.client.env.SearchableProperties    : properties search order:PROPERTIES->JVM->ENV->DEFAULT_SETTING
2024-01-11 15:36:46.874  WARN  [           main] (system) -- c.a.nacos.client.logging.NacosLogging    : Load Logback Configuration of Nacos fail, message: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
2024-01-11 15:36:46.875  WARN  [           main] (system) -- c.a.nacos.client.logging.NacosLogging    : Load Logback Configuration of Nacos fail, message: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
2024-01-11 15:36:47.253  WARN  [           main] (system) -- c.a.nacos.client.logging.NacosLogging    : Load Logback Configuration of Nacos fail, message: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
2024-01-11 15:36:47.254  INFO  [           main] (system) -- c.a.n.client.env.SearchableProperties    : properties search order:PROPERTIES->JVM->ENV->DEFAULT_SETTING
2024-01-11 15:36:47.255  INFO  [           main] (system) -- c.alibaba.nacos.client.utils.ParamUtil   : [settings] [req-serv] nacos-server port:8848
2024-01-11 15:36:47.256  INFO  [           main] (system) -- c.alibaba.nacos.client.utils.ParamUtil   : [settings] [http-client] connect timeout:1000
2024-01-11 15:36:47.257  INFO  [           main] (system) -- c.alibaba.nacos.client.utils.ParamUtil   : PER_TASK_CONFIG_SIZE: 3000.0
2024-01-11 15:36:47.295  INFO  [           main] (system) -- c.a.n.p.a.s.c.ClientAuthPluginManager    : [ClientAuthPluginManager] Load ClientAuthService com.alibaba.nacos.client.auth.impl.NacosClientAuthServiceImpl success.
2024-01-11 15:36:47.295  INFO  [           main] (system) -- c.a.n.p.a.s.c.ClientAuthPluginManager    : [ClientAuthPluginManager] Load ClientAuthService com.alibaba.nacos.client.auth.ram.RamClientAuthServiceImpl success.
2024-01-11 15:36:47.298  INFO  [           main] (system) -- c.a.n.c.a.r.identify.CredentialWatcher   : null No credential found
2024-01-11 15:36:47.573  WARN  [           main] (system) -- c.a.nacos.client.logging.NacosLogging    : Load Logback Configuration of Nacos fail, message: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
2024-01-11 15:36:47.574  WARN  [           main] (system) -- c.a.nacos.client.logging.NacosLogging    : Load Logback Configuration of Nacos fail, message: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.5)

2024-01-11 15:36:47.588  INFO  [           main] (system) -- c.a.n.c.c.impl.LocalConfigInfoProcessor  : LOCAL_SNAPSHOT_PATH:C:\Users\alleyf\nacos\config
2024-01-11 15:36:47.591  INFO  [           main] (system) -- com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client   : [RpcClientFactory] create a new rpc client of 0c1e8cb7-a469-4ab1-bb30-4a8ca86e6d4a_config-0
2024-01-11 15:36:47.605  INFO  [           main] (system) -- com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client   : [0c1e8cb7-a469-4ab1-bb30-4a8ca86e6d4a_config-0] Register server push request handler:com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient$$Lambda$583/0x000001dc3038ec18
2024-01-11 15:36:47.605  INFO  [           main] (system) -- com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client   : [0c1e8cb7-a469-4ab1-bb30-4a8ca86e6d4a_config-0] Register server push request handler:com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient$$Lambda$584/0x000001dc3038f038
2024-01-11 15:36:47.605  INFO  [           main] (system) -- com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client   : [0c1e8cb7-a469-4ab1-bb30-4a8ca86e6d4a_config-0] Registry connection listener to current client:com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient$1
2024-01-11 15:36:47.606  INFO  [           main] (system) -- com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client   : [0c1e8cb7-a469-4ab1-bb30-4a8ca86e6d4a_config-0] RpcClient init, ServerListFactory = com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient$2
2024-01-11 15:36:47.611  INFO  [           main] (system) -- com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client   : [0c1e8cb7-a469-4ab1-bb30-4a8ca86e6d4a_config-0] Try to connect to server on start up, server: {serverIp = '127.0.0.1', server main port = 8848}
2024-01-11 15:36:48.197 ERROR  [           main] (system) -- c.a.n.c.remote.client.grpc.GrpcClient    : Server check fail, please check server 127.0.0.1 ,port 9848 is available , error ={}

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:566)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:445)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client.grpc.GrpcClient.serverCheck(GrpcClient.java:196)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client.grpc.GrpcClient.connectToServer(GrpcClient.java:307)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client.RpcClient.start(RpcClient.java:359)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient.ensureRpcClient(ClientWorker.java:891)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient.getOneRunningClient(ClientWorker.java:1038)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient.queryConfig(ClientWorker.java:946)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker.getServerConfig(ClientWorker.java:402)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.NacosConfigService.getConfigInner(NacosConfigService.java:184)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.NacosConfigService.getConfig(NacosConfigService.java:96)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceBuilder.loadNacosData(NacosPropertySourceBuilder.java:85)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceBuilder.build(NacosPropertySourceBuilder.java:73)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceLocator.loadNacosPropertySource(NacosPropertySourceLocator.java:199)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceLocator.loadNacosDataIfPresent(NacosPropertySourceLocator.java:186)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceLocator.loadApplicationConfiguration(NacosPropertySourceLocator.java:141)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceLocator.locate(NacosPropertySourceLocator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:50)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:46)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:605)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:385)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:309)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
    at com.csdc.mshdcf.system.SystemApplication.main(SystemApplication.java:14)
Caused by: com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:515)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:9848
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
```

The nacos client I use is version 2.x, and the server uses nacos deployed with docker version 2.3. YAM configures the server IP and port, but as soon as I start the app, the following error appears. Why does it connect to local nacos instead of I configured the server-address. This error will appear even if I don’t write any configuration?

I want to know why and how to fix it?

Comment: first use the spring cloud alibaba 2022.0.0.0 ,nacos server 2.X need open port 8848(http) and 9848(grpc),make sure you docker is open the ports